# Bootstrap modal is coming disable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[image]When i click on the button modal comes but its disabled, i tried to remove all js and css but couldn't find the result.
As i know any js contradict with bootstrap modal, but couldn't find that js.

Its an simple modal...but dont know why its disabled

My Bundle.config file.

```
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Optimization;

    namespace ABC
    {
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit        http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js",
                        "~/Scripts/vendor-core.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/vendor-tables.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/vendor-forms.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/vendor-maps.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/module-essentials.min.js",
                //"~/Scripts/module-layout.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/module-sidebar.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/module-timeline.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/module-chat.min.js",
                //"~/Scripts/module-maps.min.js",
                      //   "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                          "~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js",

                //"~Scripts/jquery.backstretch.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/theme-core.min.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  //    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/vendor.min.css",
                      "~/Content/theme-core.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-essentials.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-layout.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-sidebar.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-sidebar-skins.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-navbar.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-timeline.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-cover.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-maps.min.css",
                      "~/Content/module-chat.min.css"));
        }
    }
  }
```

My modal---

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-       target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-      dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Disabled in the sense? What are you not able to do in that?

Comment: Just inspect the element and check which is there in the top layer?

Comment: @Arvind do you have only one modal?

Comment: @Arvind Place your modal HTML at the bottom of html page i.e. after footer or body and check